# Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': The list "Lists/Issue Manage" doesn't exist. Please fix the ListUrl attribute

Tags: development, event-receivers, feature, solution-package, elements-xml

I am working on sharepoint server 2013. and i have developed an event receiver which fires when lists items are updated. now i define the following setting inside the `elements.xml` for my solution:-

```
 <Receivers ListUrl="Lists/Issue Manage">
```

so that the event receiver will only fire on the lists which have the following url `Lists/Issue Manage`. Then i try deploying the solution using visual studio 2012, but i got the following error:-

> Error 1   Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': The
>   list "Lists/Issue Manage" doesn't exist.  Please fix the ListUrl
>   attribute.        0   0   CustomerSitesER

now i changed the feature scope from "`Web`" (which is the default) to "`Site`" , and try to re-deply the solution , where the solution got deployed without errors.
so my question is why i can not use the `ListURL` when the solution scope is defined as `Web`?

second question now when i define the feature scope as `Site` the solution was deployed successfully, but the event receiver was fired on all the lists even the lists that does not have the following url `ListUrl="Lists/Issue Manage"`. so not sure why this is happening ? as i know defining `ListURL` inside the feature's `element.xml` file should restrict the event receiver to got fired on the related lists only. but seems this is not the case.

Thanks

Comment: this statement is wrong  "only fire on the lists which have the following URL Lists/Issue Manage," <Receivers ListUrl="Lists/Issue Manage"> only run on  one list that has this path listURL path

Comment: @M.Qassas i did not get your point ? now all the lists inside any site can be accessed from the following url "/lists/" so defining "_list/Issue Manage_" means to restrict the event receiver on all the list that can be accessed from "_/lists/issue mnage_" is this correct ?in all ways the event receiver is firing on all the lists.. so what is the reason ?

Comment: this "list/Issue Manage"  is the list path for a specific one list

Comment: @M.Qassas but i have many subsites which have a list that can be accessed using "_list/issue manage_" ,, why you are assuming that i can only have one list with unique sub-url.. in my case i have 10 sub-sites and each sub-site have a list with the following url "_http://servername/subsitename/list/Maage issue_" ... in all ways why the event receiver is firing on all the lists   ??

Comment: Should you join at this http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46670/discussion-between-m-qassas-and-john-g to discuss  in details

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some discrepancy. The error you are getting shows the Url as `Lists/Risk Issue` whereas the Url present in elements.xml file is `Lists/Issue Manage`.

`ListUrl` attribute works for `Web` based scopes and hence it will fire the events in all lists present in subsites where the feature is activated. Finally `ListUrl` attribute is ignored if scope of feature is changed to `Site`. See [Event Receiver Firing for all Lists - even when ListUrl is set](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8079/event-receiver-firing-for-all-lists-even-when-listurl-is-set) for more information.

Comment: Sorry i wrongly typed the list URL. so the list url is "_lists/Issue Manage_". first question now in my case i set the scope of the solution as "Web" be selecting this from the Scope dropdown list , and i define the following inside the element.xml   "_<Receivers ListTemplateId="101">_"  this mean that the event receiver should only work on document libraries.. but i tried adding an issue tracking item and the event receiver got fired!.

Comment: second point now in my case the lists have the following display name "_Manage_" while their urls are "_Issue Manage_" as i have rename the lists long time ago (from "_Issue Manage_" to "_Manage_" using the UI).. so their names are different that their urls,, now when i use ListURL should i include the display name "_Manage_" or the url "_Issue Manage_". third point now regardless of using ListURL or ListTempleteid both is going to fire the event receiver for all the lists (so restricting the ER using these approaches are not working)...so what is the reasons?

Comment: May I suggest you to try this on a fresh site collection?

Comment: additional note now i have also tried to specify the scope inside the elements.xml as follow ""_<Receivers ListTemplateId="101" Scope="Web">_ but still the event revicer will get fired on all the lists

Comment: the problem is that my event receiver reference and use many custom site columns,, so it is not easy to create a new site collection with all the custom modifications inside it ..any other suggestions ?and can you please adivce on my above 3 question inside my comments ?

Comment: You don't need to deploy whole solution of yours, just create an empty project with event receiver and check if above works in new site collection. That will determine if your current site is in good state or not.

Comment: so what could be causing my site  collection to be in a bad state ? as the event receiver is firing but it is firing on all lists ,, so this indicates that the problem might be within the event receiver itself and not inside the site collection is this correct ?

Comment: second point i have, now i read a lot of articles where users reported that the ListURL is not working as expected. so to make things simpler, i can deploy the feature as-is with "_listtempleteid=1100_" (Issue Tracking),then inside my event receiver itself to add a condition to check the list name and/or the content type inside the Event Receiver, and then execute the update operations only if the list name and content type meet the requirements.in this case whenever the ER get fired, the actual update operations will not happen unless the list name and/or content type is met. what do u think?

Comment: If that is the case you can programatically attach the event with a particular list.

Comment: but in my case i have a list named "Manage" and this list can be found inside many sub-sites ,, and I want my event receiver to get attached to all the lists which have their names (title) = "Manage" so it is not a single list .. it is a list that can be found on multiple sub-sites... so i can define the scope of the event receiver to be Web , which mean the event receiver will get fired on all the lists inside the sub-site, but i will add a condition inside the ER to check for the list name ="Manage".

Comment: ..i know this will cause the ER to get fired always(maybe a performance drawback) , but no effect will happen unless the items are under a list named "Manage",, i mean this appraoch is a workaround to the listurl and listtempleteid which seems is not working in my case.. what do you think ?